# Problem with a hand in Texas hold'em

Tags: hand-history, no-limit, game-mechanics, hand-reading

We play as friends and keep arguing over a certain hand dealt. The scenario is on the last card dealt it becomes a straight on the table, say 23456, I understand if someone has a 7 then that would win but what if the straight is the best hand, is the pot split? One guy says their two pair would win but I don't agree .

Any help would be great.

Comment: in case _no-one_ of the players have any `7`, the pot is split since all of you have hit a straight, regardless your holding hands; The board just gave you the best hand and that only matters (the best 5-card combination doesn't have to include your 2 cards). However, even if someone has a `A7` card isn't guarantee to win since another player with `87` wins with the even higher straight.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Thanks for clearing it up i will have great pleasure in telling them they was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of hold-em is that your hand is the best possible five-card combination *from all seven cards*. So, in this case, yes, it is a split pot. All players (as you describe them) have a 6-high straight. That's the best possible hand, so that's *their* hand.

Comment: @Adamjayes Happy to help; if you enjoyed the answer, please feel free to mark it as such. It helps both my reputation and yours.

Answer (score -2):

The winning hand , its the 5 top cards with your hand you can make.

34567 -> Take the pot over 23456 , and 2 pairs.

Hope i could help :)

Comment: This answer doesn't help the OP distinguish between the 23456 on the board and the two pair that his opponent thought should win the pot, which was his actual question. Jim's answer is both correct and complete.

Comment: This answer is somewhat unclear. Ido, Can you clarify your meaning with less arrows and more plain language? It's likely that the previous answers are clear enough to cover the questions needs anyway.